# Not Allow Text to Move my Icon Instead Wrap to the Next Line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the text within a button wrap to the next line instead of pushing my icon out of the way, I still want the icon centred on the right of the button.

I have tried different displays on the icon, tried adding `whitespace: nowrap`.

I have considered adding like a maximum line length to the button but could not figure out how to do that, almost as if the text and icon are occupying different spaces.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible").forEach((coll) => {
  coll.addEventListener("click", () => {
    coll.classList.toggle("active");

    const content = coll.nextElementSibling;

    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
      content.style.borderWidth = 0;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
      content.style.borderWidth = "1px";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.005);
}

.icon {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_231938.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  float: right;
  background-size: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  transition: rotate .25s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible"> Check the Following Connectors for Loose Crimps, Insertion, Splay Female Connector Crimps, and Whether They are Missing  <div class="icon"></div></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your expected one?

```css
.collapsible {
  background-color: white;
  color: #021032;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 17px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #D1D3D4;
  border-radius: 6px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin: 5px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.005);
  text-align: left;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
}

.icon {
  background-image: url("https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_231938.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  transition: rotate .25s ease-in-out;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="collapsible"> Check the Following Connectors for Loose Crimps, Insertion, Splay Female Connector Crimps, and Whether They are Missing  <div class="icon"><div></button>
```

Comment: Hello, this is my expected result, however this solution breaks my other buttons. The buttons with the text that doesn't completely fill it out has the has the icon hugging the right of the text. The icon no longer floats to the right of the button.

Comment: After further trial and error, I added justify-content: space between; to the flex container, and that seems to have fixed it for now.